# everything except inline code tags working in Markdown

Tags: markdown, ghost

Here's the Markdown. It's a Ghost blog hosted by Digital Ocean. I'm using the Nginx web server on CentOS 7. The inline code looks fine in Ghost's preview but I published the post and it does not show up in safari or in Chrome when I publish it. The URL is https://linuxhowto.tech/managing-users-and-groups/

### Adding new users

While you can use `vipw` to edit the user configuration files, it is better to run `useradd`.

`vim /etc/default/useradd`

The output should look similar to this:

`GROUP=100

HOME=/home

INACTIVE=-1

EXPIRE=

SHELL=/bin/bash

SKEL=/etc/skel

CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes`

#### Useradd examples

- `useradd -c "Comment here" sarah -s /bin/bash` sets a comment         (-c) and defines the default shell (-s)
- `useradd bob -s /usr/sbin/nologin` sets `nologin` as the users's default shell because many users don't need shell access
- `useradd -m -u 1201 -G ops,dev linda` adds user, adds home directory (-m), adds user to groups *ops* and *dev* (-G), assigns _UID 1201+ (-u)
- `useradd` creates a locked account until you run `passwd user`

#### The login configuration file

The `/etc/login.defs` file sets the configuration for the for the *Shadow Password Suite.* The following are some of its most significant attributes:

> - `MOTD_FILE`: Defines the file that is used as *message of the day* file. In this file, you can include messages to be displayed after the user has successfully logged into the server.
> - `ENV_PATH`: Defines the `$PATH` variable, a list of directories that should be searched for executable files after logging in.
> - `PASS_MAX_DAYS`, `PASS_MIN_DAYS`, and `PASS_WARN_AGE`: Define the default password expiration properties when creating new users.
> - `UID_MIN`: The first UID to use when creating new users.
> - `CREATE_HOME`: Indicates whether or not to create a home directory for new users.
> - `USERGROUPS_ENAB`: Set to yes to create a private group for all new users. That means that a new user has a group with the same name as the user as its default group. If set to no, all users are made a member of the group users. [^n]

#### System-wide Bash shell startup files

- `/etc/profile` runs system-wide environment variables and startup         scripts
- `/etc/bashrc` contains system-wide aliases and functions [^n]

#### Bash shell personal startup files

While creating a user, `useradd` copies the `/etc/skel` user environment configuration files to the new user's home directory. The following are the default configuration files:

- `~/.bash_profile` contains personal environment variables and startup scripts
- `~/.bashrc` contains personal aliases and functions
- `~/.bash_logout` contains personal scripts to run on logout[^n]

### Using usermod to modify users

These are a couple common use cases for `usermod`:

- `usermod -g sales mike` adds *mike* to sales as *primary* group
- `usermod -aG ops lisa` adds *lisa* to ops as a *secondary* group

### Managing password properties

Here are some example use cases for `passwd` and `chage`:

- `chage -E 2018-12-31 bob` sets Bob's account to expire on a specific date
- `chage -l linda` lists account aging information
- `passwd -n 30 -x 90 lori -w 3` sets *minimum password age* of 30 days, a *maximum password age* of 90 days (-w), and starts *warning* the user 3-days before the password expires (-w)

### Linux group management

The `useradd` command creates a default *primary group* with the same name as the user.

When a user creates a file, the group owner will be set to that user's primary group. Users have access to files owned by their secondary groups.

Use the `id` command to list a user's group memberships:

`id linda`

The output should look something like this:
`uid=1002(linda) gid=1003(account) groups=1003(account),1001(sales)`

A common use case for secondary groups is to share documents between departments with a file server.

### Creating groups

To create a new group, you can use the `vigr` command to directly modify the `/etc/group` file or you can run the `groupadd` command.

- `groupadd devs` adds a group called *dev*
- `groupadd -g 404 devproject` adds a group called *devproject* with *Group ID (GUID) 404*
- `grep devproject /etc/group` to confirm that you successfully added a group

#### Modifying group membership

- `usermod -g 1003 frank` changes frank's **primary** group to      account, assigning GUID of 1003
- `usermod -aG dev lori` adds account as a *secondary*                          group for lori
- `usermod -g sales anouk` changes anouk's *primary* group to sales

---

[^n]: Excerpt from Sander van Vugt's [Red Hat® RHCSA™/RHCE® 7 Cert Guide Premium Edition](http://www.sandervanvugt.com/book-red-hat-rhcsa-rhce-7-cert-guide/)
[^n]: Derived from  [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/profile.html)
[^n]: Derived from  [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/profile.html)

Answer (score 1):

For now, I just switched themes for a quick solution and it worked. These are my notes for an RHCSA course so just getting them online fast is my goal at the moment as some other students in the course expressed interest so I'll post my notes as a series of posts. At some point, I'll customize the CSS in the original theme I was using.